# Deploy angular-meteor on server?

Tags: heroku, angular-meteor

I'm using Angular(Ionic)-Meteor method (http://www.angular-meteor.com/) to create my app. It worked local perfectly.

However, when I put it on Paas server like Heroku, OpenShift, I got error with angular like this (from browser console):

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'InboxCtrl' is not a function, got undefined http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=InboxCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

This error show at both server (Heroku and OpenShift)

Has anyone done this before and can help me with deploying my app?

Answer (score 0):

I've already solve my problem.

In case anyone else need it:

https://forums.meteor.com/t/deploy-angular-meteor-on-openshift/25333/2

Thanks.
Close now.